# MS Access: How do I include Is Null into the results of an IIF Statement for the criteria of a query (If search field is left blank then add "is Null)

Tags: ms-access

I am looking for some help. I have made a sample table with four fields:

COUNTRY
CITY
LOCATION
IS_EMPLOYEE

I have created a search form with these four fields as inputs and a search button to launch the following saved Query:

```
SELECT NullTest.Country, NullTest.City, NullTest.Location, NullTest.IsPerm FROM NullTest WHERE ((NullTest.Country) Like "*" & Forms!ATest!input_COUNTRY & "*" Or (NullTest.Country) Is Null) And ((NullTest.City) Like "*" & Forms!Atest!input_CITY & "*" Or (NullTest.City) Is Null)
```

So far so good, I search for all in ITALY and it returns all with the country ITALY and all other fields, whether they are blank (NULL) or not

However with that code I then search for Country=ITALY and City=MILAN it returns all records in ITALY and MILAN and where the city is left blank

What I am trying to achieve is:
Is a user leaves City blank, then search for Country = ITALY AND City Is Null
If a user filles in City as well then search for Country = ITALY AND City = abc (but do not include blanks)

I have tried many variations for two das but have not had any results:

I have tried NZ(City) in all flavours, this returns 0 rows
I have tried all the fields without the "OR Is Null" option, while this works well for exact data, it excludes blanks which I don't want since the data is "dirty"

The closest I got was:

```
((NullTest.City) = IIF(IsNull(Forms!ATest!_inputCITY),(NullTest.City) Is Null,(NullTest.City)=Like "*" & Forms!Atest!input_CITY & "*"))
```

But Access returns the error that it is too complicated when running the query (it allows me to save it)
Note if I replace "Is Null" with " "ROME" " it will return "ROME" in the query if the search field is blank, so in theory the IIF Statement works, just not with the "Is Null"

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Are

Comment: Not surprised last attempt fails, `=LIKE` is not valid syntax. Instead of trying to build complex dynamic parameterized query object, consider using VBA to build filter and apply to form or report. Also might have better luck calculating fields to provide a value if null and applying filter to those fields: `SELECT Nz(Country, "None") AS AdjCtry, Nz(City, "None") AS AdjCity, ...`. This way can eliminate the `OR IS NULL`.

Comment: Also, operators (=, <>, < , >, LIKE) cannot be dynamic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341652/microsoft-access-query-should-return-true-or-true-and-false-only-returns-true/66345170#66345170

Comment: If you use `Is Null` then only null fields will be filtered. I think when one search criteria is left blank then filter should work only on one field so that you can get all results for other fields. Suppose one has selected `Country=Italy` then filter criteria would like `SELCET t.Country, t.City, t.xyz WHERE t.Country= '" & frm!f1!fCountry & "'"` And if he selects both then criteria will be like `SELCET t.Country, t.City, t.xyz WHERE t.Country= '" & frm!f1!fCountry & "' t.City= '" & frm!f1!fCity &"'"`