# How to correctly make a query design criteria with multiple parameters?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a query that prompts the user to enter a single character or hit enter for all. I am able to do this with this query:
`Like [Enter Zone (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 21, P, A, F, C, T, B, E, S) or Hit Enter for All] & "*"`

However, when the user says "OK" and requests for all, I need the query to NOT include 20 and 21.
I tried adding `Or Not Like ("20", "21")` or `(Not Like "20" And Not Like "21")` at the end but I get an error.

I feel like this is something simple but I can't figure out the order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing in that parameter prevents user from entering "X" or "&" or any combination of characters and query will still run but not return records. Also, by using wildcard, entry of "2" will return 2, 20, 21, not just 2. Aside from that, I don't think will be successful trying to build that conditional criteria in query object. Advise using VBA behind a 'search' form to build criteria and apply to form or report. User input to controls on form can be validated. At least use a form for user input and have query reference form controls as parameter input. Popup inputs cannot be validated.

Comment: Even with referencing controls on form, I think this conditional parameterization within query will be difficult, if not impossible. Operators (=, <, >, LIKE, NOT LIKE) cannot be dynamic, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341652/microsoft-access-query-should-return-true-or-true-and-false-only-returns-true

Comment: If my question is impossible, then please at least tell me how to fix the entry of "2" without showing "20" and "21". If the user clicks "Ok", I would still need it to show all (doesn't matter if 20 and 21 are included).

Comment: The how was shown in link I provided but I have given you an answer using your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numeric criteria with choices like 2, 20, 21 means cannot concatenate with wildcard so 20 and 21 are not retrieved when 2 is selected.

Using a popup input prompt with that long statement in query will look messy.

```
LIKE IIf([Enter Zone (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 21, P, A, F, C, T, B, E, S) or Hit Enter for All] <> "", [Enter Zone (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 21, P, A, F, C, T, B, E, S) or Hit Enter for All], "*")
```

Using a reference to form control a little less messy:

```
LIKE IIf(NOT [Forms!formname!controlname] IS NULL, [Forms!formname!controlname], "*")
```

Either will allow returning records matching value entered or returning all if nothing entered. This will not solve the issue of excluding 20 and 21 from all - for that I recommend using a VBA solution that builds filter criteria and applies to form or report.