# MS Access Query: Use a passed parameter for a list of records or the parameter " ALL" to generate the whole list

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my query in the criteria field. The parameter is contained on a form in the combobox cboReportSender. cboReportSender contains a list of departments that I run reports for. Also contained in the list is " ALL". When this is selected, I wish the report to display all records. I'm sure that the query is looking for a field literally containing "Like *"
Am I going at this from a wrong angle?

`IIf([Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender]=Trim(" ALL"),"Like *",[Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Access Query Should return true or true and false, only returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341652/microsoft-access-query-should-return-true-or-true-and-false-only-returns-true)

Comment: Can you use Dynamic-SQL?

Comment: Please show full SQL query not line snippet.

Comment: Thanks June7, Great Info, I am going to try to come at it from that angle. I'll let you know..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wondered whether your combobox selected a numerical value or an alphanumerical value.  But when I created a database for testing, neither worked for me in combination with the operator `Like *` .  I needed to typ `Like '\*'` , with a single inverted comma before and after the asterisk. 
Even better, adding this inverted comma's works with both numerical and alphanumerical values.

The second thing I needed to change was, to add a second like-operator.  In the end, your criterion would become :
`IIf([Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender]=Trim(" ALL"),"Like '*'","Like '" & [Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender] & "'")`

Comment: Thanks for the time you've put into this problem. I put that code in but it still didn't work... With that said, I'm experiencing brain fog today from some medical procedures I'm undergoing.  I'll get back to you in a few days..

Answer (score 0):

Consider returning the field itself when combobox selects `ALL`.

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE myDepartmentField = IIf(
    TRIM([Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender]) = 'ALL', 
    myDepartmentField,
    TRIM([Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender])
)
```

And if combobox is empty, use `NZ` to default to field itself.

```sql
WHERE myDepartmentField = IIf(
    TRIM([Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender]) = 'ALL', 
    myDepartmentField,
    TRIM(
         NZ(
             [Forms]![frmRunReport]![cboReportSender],
             myDepartmentField
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! The default in the cboReportSender box is "ALL".  If I'm reading your code correctly it is returning either  the word "ALL" or the Department Name... How do I get the query to it to display the whole list of departments for my report?

Comment: Did you run the SQL? Logic indicates that if it combobox reads 'ALL', the `WHERE` condition resolves to `myDepartmentField = myDepartmentField` which is same as `1=1`, so all non-NULL records are returned.

Comment: Thanks Parfait for explaining. After pondering, I finally got it.. I chose this solution and it worked perfectly... I can now use 1 report that will change configuration on the fly based on the choices that the user makes on the calling form (frmRunReport) this was the only part that I was struggling with... SQL is king...