# Using Switch Function or nested iif in an Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a small little Access program that sums hours of employees, with queries for Daily, Weekly, Monthly, and from the start of the year, all accessed from an easy to read form.

I have been asked to make an option group to filter employees by fulltime, seasonal, or both.  But an issue I have is that I can only access the PAYRULENAME from the table which begins 'FT' for Fulltime such as FTADBRK1 but Seasonal can be a whole mishmash of possibilities, just not beginning with "FT".  Still, I did not think this to be an issue.

Since I already have the original queries done, I thought I could simply add an additional column and constraint for each query instead of making additional queries.  So I tried some various methods. Such as:

Switch([Forms]![MyForm]![EmpType].Value="FT",Left([PAYRULENAME],2)="FT",[Forms]![MyForm]![EmpType].Value="S",Left([PAYRULENAME],2)<>"FT"[Forms]![MyForm]![EmpType].Value="All",[PAYRULENAME])

Where EmpType is a textbox that programmatically gives a value for the option group instead of 1,2, or 3.  This works and I don't think this is where the issue is.

But using the above switch function gives a -1 for Fulltime or a 0 for Seasonal (S) and doesn't filter the query. (The last option is fine - but it would be nice to give an FT or S in a column instead of the entire PAYRULENAME).

I have also tried nested iif statements to no avail.  Here is one: IIF([Forms]![MyForm]![EmpType].Value="All",[PAYRULENAME],IIF([Forms]![MyForm]![EmpType].Value="FT",Left([PAYRULENAME],2)="FT",Left([PAYRULENAME],2)<>"FT"))

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Access Query Should return true or true and false, only returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341652/microsoft-access-query-should-return-true-or-true-and-false-only-returns-true)

Comment: You have a calculated field in query that returns "FT" or "S" and apply filter criteria to that field? You have an UNBOUND control on form to specify "FT" or "S" or "All" as filter parameter?